# My RiverPod StateNotifierProvider duplicates and replaces values

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod on my Flutter mobile app and on my main class I have declared a global variable :

```
final messagesProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<MessagesData, List<Message>>((ref) => MessagesData());
```

And here's my MessagesData class :

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'message_model.dart';

class MessagesData extends StateNotifier<List<Message>> {
  MessagesData() : super([]);

  int getCount() => state.length;

  void addMessagesList(List<Message> messages) {
    state = [...state, ...messages];
  }

  void addMessage(Message message) {
    state = [message, ...state];
  }
}
```

I have a screen on white I'm trying to display a ListView and so I'm using this provider to watch my MessagesDaa and rebuild the ListView whenever a new message is added :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:veoxerlivetexter/Providers/message_provider.dart';
import 'package:veoxerlivetexter/main.dart';
import 'package:veoxerlivetexter/models/message_model.dart';
import 'package:veoxerlivetexter/widgets/message_card.dart';

class MessageList extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MessageList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MessageListState createState() => _MessageListState();
}

class _MessageListState extends ConsumerState<MessageList> {
  final MessageProvider messageProvider = MessageProvider();
  bool isDoneFetchingMessages = true;
  List<Message> messages = [];
  Future initiateMessages() async {
    final List<Message> messages = await messageProvider.getLastMessages(4);
    ref.read(messagesProvider.notifier).addMessagesList(messages);
    isDoneFetchingMessages = true;
  }

  Future<void> onFetchMessages() async {
    final int lastMessageId =
        ref.read(messageTrackerProvider.notifier).getMessageId();
    final List<Message> newMessages =
        await messageProvider.getMessages(lastMessageId);
    ref.read(messagesProvider.notifier).addMessagesList(newMessages);
    ref
        .read(messageTrackerProvider.notifier)
        .updateMessageId(newMessages.last.id!);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initiateMessages();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    messages = ref.watch(messagesProvider);
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: onFetchMessages,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              for (final message in messages)
                MessageCard(
                  message: message,
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I'm doing here is that I initiate a few message on the first rendering of this widget, and then I have another screen on which the user can add a nw message. When a new message is added the watch function is executed and my listview is rendered again and I have an updated list as a result.
On the add screen i have the following line :

```
ref.read(messagesProvider.notifier).addMessage(message);
```

But on the second adding I get a list with a duplicate of the newly added element, on the 3rd adding I get 2 duplicated and so on. I tried everything and I still understand what I'm doing wrong.

I tried changing to a stateless widget but I still got the same problem. For example, if I'm starting with a list of messages like the following :

```
['msg 1', 'msg 2']
```

When I'll add a first element I will get :

```
['msg 3', 'msg 1', 'msg 2', ...]
```

But when I add the 2nd I get :

```
['msg 4', 'msg 4', 'msg 3', ...]
```

And the 3rd :

```
['msg 5', 'msg 5', 'msg 5', ...]
```

And so on.
And I noticed that after the first add, if I comment the addMessage line, somehow my provider state is still getting updated as if the line wasn't commented.

Comment: How did you fix this?